# Como darle un valor a un elemento en una tabla? React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, select, table

estoy creando una aplicación para agendar citas y tengo una tabla con las horas disponibles, mi pregunta es, como puedo hacer para que el usuario pinche sobre la hora que desea y este valor se guarde en una variable? Estoy ocupando React y TailwindCSS para realizar este proyecto. Esta es mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el código que tengo hasta ahora de la tabla:

```
<div className='w-fit h-fit shadow-md rounded-lg'>
          <table className="bg-white border-2 border-slate-300">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th className='p-2 border-x-2 border-slate-300'>Hoy</th>
                <th className='p-2 border-x-2 border-slate-300'>Mañana</th>
                <th className='p-2 border-x-2 border-slate-300'>proximo dia</th>
                <th className='p-2 border-x-2 border-slate-300'>proximo dia</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>9:00</td>
                <td>9:00</td>
                <td>9:00</td>
                <td>9:00</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>10:00</td>
                <td>10:00</td>
                <td>10:00</td>
                <td>10:00</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>11:00</td>
                <td>11:00</td>
                <td>11:00</td>
                <td>11:00</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>12:00</td>
                <td>12:00</td>
                <td>12:00</td>
                <td>12:00</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>13:00</td>
                <td>13:00</td>
                <td>13:00</td>
                <td>13:00</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>14:00</td>
                <td>14:00</td>
                <td>14:00</td>
                <td>14:00</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿utilizando React o JavaScript sin "framework"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes egregar a cada evento td una funcion que se lance en el evento onclick con los parametros que equivalgan a ese día y hora.

```
<td onClick={()=>guardarCita("hoy", "9:00"}>9:00</td>
```

Luego crear la función guardarCita que recupera la hora y ya luego haces lo que quieras con ella.

```
function guardarCita(day, hour){
   console.log(`tienes cita para ${day} a las ${hour}`);
}
```

De todas maneras, si estás usando react, se puede optimizar el codigo para pintar la tabla